# Appending exel cell values to a list with Openpyxl with data only

Tags: python, excel, append, openpyxl

I'm learning Python and my first programme is to read certain cell values over multiple worksheets is a workbook and append these values to a nested list, which I will then use to write to another file. I would like them to come out as the data in the cell with none of the underlying formatting or equations and have used the data_only=True argument to try and achieve this:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('sample_file.xlsx', data_only=True)
ws= wb.worksheets[0]
dct={}

for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    dct['%s' % sheet.title]= []
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col = sheet.max_column):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value is None:
               pass 
            else:
                print cell.value
                dct['%s' % sheet.title].append(cell.value)
print(dct)
```

When the cell values are printed in the console, the date and time values that are in the workbook come out as desired e.g.

> 2019-09-01 00:00:00

However when the nested lists are printed, the date and time come out as follows:

> datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 1, 0, 0)

Is there a way to append the cell value with the data only?

Comment: Read about [datetime.datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime)